# XmlTextReader.Encoding is null after constructing from stream with encoding="utf-8"

Tags: c#, .net, xml, encoding

According to the code documentation

```
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Gets the encoding of the document.
    //
    // Returns:
    //     The encoding value. If no encoding attribute exists, and there is no byte-order
    //     mark, this defaults to UTF-8.
```

so I would expect `XmlTextReader.Encoding` to never be null.

However, I find it is null when I run

```
var stream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(
@"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8""?>
...
</xml>"));
var xmlTextReader = new XmlTextReader(stream);
```

Is there some parameter I am missing in the constructor?

Comment: `XmlTextReader` has been deprecated since **.NET 2.0**.  From the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmltextreader?view=net-5.0): *Starting with the .NET Framework 2.0, we recommend that you create [`XmlReader`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlreader?view=net-5.0) instances by using the [`XmlReader.Create`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlreader.create?view=net-5.0) method to take advantage of new functionality.*

Comment: But, logically, they encoding can't be detected until the reader begins to process the stream and encounters a byte order mark or XML declaration.

Comment: @dbc The entire reason why I was using `XmlTextReader` was for the `Encoding` property because I couldn't find it on `XmlReader`. Is the same functionality hidden somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

The xml posted in the question is not valid xml (...). I presume it denotes some more xml content.

Having said that, XMLTextReader cannot know the encoding type until unless it processes the content inside of it. In order to do so we an call the [MoveToContent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlreader.movetocontent?view=net-5.0) method. Once the method is executed, the encoding can be fetched from the reader.

```
var stream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(
            @"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8""?>
                <TestXmlNode>
            </xml>"));

var xmlTextReader = new XmlTextReader(stream);
xmlTextReader.MoveToContent();
var encoding = xmlTextReader.Encoding;
```